# Ajax метод POST не отправляет на сервер данные

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

Дело в том, что ajax не отправляет данные на сервер. Подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего такое может быть.

Страница:

```
         $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/action/ObnovStatUser', // URL запроса
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { // Параметры запроса (опционально)
                StatMail: "true",
                ComMail: "true",
                id: "43"
            },
            success: function(data){   /* функция которая будет выполнена после успешного запроса.  */
            console.log(data);            /* В переменной data содержится ответ от index.php. */
            }
        });
```

А это прием (/action/ObnovStatUser):

```
       if ($Module == 'ObnovStatUser'){ 
             echo "OTVET-".$_POST['StatMail']."-FFFFFFFFFFFFF";
          }
```

В консоле отображается что-то вроде этого: OTVET--FFFFFFFFFFFFF. Т.е. получается, что $_POST['StatMail'] нету. Как такое может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите строку с dataType и затем сделайте `var_dump($_POST);`

PS. Попробуйте заменить `method` на `type`. Доки тут api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: Убрал строку, сделал var_dump($_POST); но массив пустой. NULL

Comment: Тогда наберите в самом начале php крипта `var_dump($_POST);die;` и пришлите результат. И какая верси jQquery?

Comment: Да все тоже самое, пустой массив

Comment: Если это легаси модуль, то не исключено, что используете старую версию jQuery. Тогда попробуйте заменить `method` на `type`

Доки тут https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: поменял на type, заработало

Answer (score 1):

если ObnovStatUser это папка то

```
url: '/action/ObnovStatUser/name.php', // URL запроса
```

если это .php то

```
url: '/action/ObnovStatUser.php', // URL запроса
```

Comment: Нет, и не папка и не файл. Это модуль)

Comment: я просто на пхп не писал пол года

Comment: Ничего страшного. Это особенность моего сайта, о которой ты знать не мог)